# Proving that the supremum of $(a,b)$ is $b$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was trying to prove it this way. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$.
Let $ I=(a,b)$.
As for all $x\in I$,$x<b$, we get $b$ is an upper bound. let $u=\sup I$, then $u\leq b$. If $u=b$ it's done. Otherwise, let's suppose $u<b$. Furthermore, for all $x\in I$, $a<x$ and $x\leq u$, so $a<u$, then $u\in I$...

Can I get somewhere this way?

Comment: You want to focus on the top end of the interval and find a number in the interval which is larger than $u$.

Comment: Now you have that $a<u<b$ with the work you have already done. This contradicts $u$ being the sup. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = \sup I$. Obviously, $u>a$ and as you pointed out, $u\leq b$. So $u \in (a, b]$. If $u < b$, then $u < {1\over 2}(u+b) < b$, so there exists a point in $I$ that is greater than $u$. That means that if $u<b$, $u$ is not an upper bound. That is a contradiction and therefore you conclude that $u=b$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $b$ is an upper bound.  Let's just assume that $u < b$.  Then either $u < a < b$ in which case $b > \frac{ b + a}{2} > a > u$, so $u$ is not an upper bound to $I$ or $a < u < b$ in which case $a <u <  \frac{b + u}{2} < b$ so that $u$ is not an upper bound.